# Trouble migrating React Navigation v4 Deep Link configuration to React Navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack

I'm having some trouble migrating my deep-link from React Navigation v4 to React Navigation v5.

For context, my deep linking has been working perfectly in React Navigation v5 with a tab bar navigator and stack navigators in each tab.

Here's what that looked like:

```
const MainApp = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    DiscoverTabStack: { screen: DiscoverTabStack, path: "" },
    GroupTabStack: { screen: GroupTabStack, path: "" },
    ProfileTabStack: { screen: ProfileTabStack, path: "" },
  },
);

const DiscoverTabStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Discover: { screen: DiscoverScreen, path: "discover" },
    DetailedActivityFromDeepLink: {
      screen: DetailedActivityFromDeepLinkScreen,
      path: "discover/activites/:id",
    },
  }
```

With React Navigation v4, I'm able to successfully deep link into the app to the correct place. However, I'm having some trouble with React Navigation v5. Below is how I'm approaching it with Reach Navigation v5.

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const DiscoverStack = createStackNavigator();

const prefixes = Linking.makeUrl("myapp://");
const linking = {
  prefixes: [prefixes],
  config: {
    screens: {
      DiscoverStack: {
        path: "",
        screens: {
          Discover: {
            path: "discover",
          },
          DetailedActivityFromDeepLink: {
            path: "discover/activites/:id",
            parse: {
              id: (id) => `${id}`,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

const DiscoverScreens = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  return (
    <DiscoverStack.Navigator mode="card">
      <DiscoverStack.Screen
        name="Discover"
        component={DiscoverScreen}
      />
      <DiscoverStack.Screen
        name="DetailedActivityFromDeepLink"
        component={DetailedActivityFromDeepLinkScreen}
      />
    </DiscoverStack.Navigator>
  );
};

render() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <NavigationContainer linking={linking}>
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Discover"
            component={DiscoverScreens}
          />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Unfortunately, the above is not working. What may be wrong with my approach? How does one deep-link into an app that has tab bars with stack navigators in each tab?

I'm sure that this is a challenge for the majority of apps out there, so it'll be awesome for some help!! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> What may be wrong with my approach?

In your root navigator (`Tab.Navigator`), you call your screen `Discover`, but in the linking config, you have written `DiscoverStack`.

The linking config needs to have the same names as you have your screens.

Comment: There's a playground in the React Navigation docs where you can test your link and config to see how to link gets parsed.

No, it's not possible to add path to each screen.

Comment: Hey Satya--thanks for reaching out and helping! I was able to get it to work. However, the deep linking only appears to be working when I'm trying to open my app://discover/activites/:id. However, this only works when I'm NOT on the Discover tab. Why is this behavior happening? Also, the at times, the destination screen segues half-way and then dismisses itself automatically. Why is this the case?